# Save Crosstab as PDF - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have created a crosstab with Matplotlib, however when trying to save it with plt.savefig, I only get a blank picture as PDF output.

How do I save my crosstab plot as a PDF?

```
  df = credit_cards_avg  #df is just a data frame

    crosstab = pd.crosstab(df[attribute], df['credit_default'])
    # Normalize the cross tab to sum to 1:
    crosstab_normalized = crosstab.div(crosstab.sum(1).astype(float), axis=0)

    crosstab_normalized.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, 
                   title='Default by ' + str(attribute) + ' class')

    plt.savefig("/home/daniele/dm-local/ps-default-class.pdf") #outputs blank file
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have a [mcve] available here. Else, you will probably not get any useful answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that there is a 'format' argument of savefig()

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Try this and see what happens

```
plt.savefig("/home/daniele/dm-local/ps-default-class.pdf", format='pdf')
```